# Using ROS subscribers in Unreal Engine

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Has anyone had any experience with using ROS subscribers inside the Unreal Engine?
My Unreal game will crash as soon as `ros::NodeHandle.spinOnce()` is called.

My Header: TestingSubs.h

```
#pragma once
#include <ros.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <baxter_core_msgs/EndpointState.h>
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "TestingSubs.generated.h"

UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class WALLCLIMBING_API UTestingSubs : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UTestingSubs();

    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
    
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent( float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction ) override;
    
    void StartUp();
    
    void MyCallback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState& msg);
    char *ros_master = "192.168.1.120";
    ros::NodeHandle MyNode;
};
```

My cpp: TestingSubs.cpp

```
#include "WallClimbing.h"
#include "TestingSubs.h"

// Sets default values for this component's properties
UTestingSubs::UTestingSubs()
{
    // Set this component to be initialized when the game starts, and to be ticked every frame.  You can turn these features
    // off to improve performance if you don't need them.
    bWantsBeginPlay = true;
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;
}


// Called when the game starts
void UTestingSubs::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    StartUp();
}


// Called every frame
void UTestingSubs::TickComponent( float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction )
{
    Super::TickComponent( DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction );
    MyNode.spinOnce();
}

void UTestingSubs::MyCallback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState& msg)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Callback was called"));
}

void Callback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState& msg)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Callback was called"));
}

void UTestingSubs::StartUp()
{
    MyNode.initNode(ros_master);
    ros::Subscriber< baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState > Mysub("/robot/limb/right/endpoint_state/", &Callback);
    MyNode.subscribe(Mysub);
}
```

Any suggestions of how I could subscribe from within Unreal would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: image of debug added.[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252993/using-ros-subscribers-in-unreal-engine/) by [dbliam](https://answers.ros.org/users/29162/dbliam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-26**:
Minor, but: we don't really close questions if they are answered. Accepting the correct answer makes it much more obvious from the question listing that it has been answered.

We do close questions that are spam, outdated, etc.

**Comment by [dbliam](https://answers.ros.org/users/29162/dbliam/) on 2017-01-26**:
Oops. Thank you for pointing that out, noted for future instances. Thanks again for your help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-26**:
No problem. Not a big thing, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason this code was crashing was that

```
ros::Subscriber< baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState > Mysub("/robot/limb/right/endpoint_state/", &Callback);
```

was being declared within one of the public functions, this was leading to it falling out of scope when the callback tried to use it, I believe. The fix for me was to make this `ros::subscriber` a global variable.

---

Originally posted by [dbliam](https://answers.ros.org/users/29162/dbliam/) with karma: 11 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-03-01**:
Hi @dblian,

where did you touch in order to be able to use ROS on your Unreal Project?

I've tried CMakeLists.txt of the Unreal Project but was not enough.

I'm using Ubuntu, BTW, but the process you have followed should work on both OS.